# Why OpenZepplin always use private visibility for state variables?

Tags: solidity, security, state-variable

Why OpenZepplin always use private visibility with getter functions for its state variables? I can't find a reason why they are not using public, is there any potential security or gas cost difference when using private instead of public?
    mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;

```
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

uint256 private _totalSupply;

/**
 * @dev See {IERC20-totalSupply}.
 */
function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
    return _totalSupply;
}

/**
 * @dev See {IERC20-balanceOf}.
 */
function balanceOf(address account) public view returns (uint256) {
    return _balances[account];
}
```

This pattern is repeated in all their contracts:
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See issue [#1174](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/issues/1174) in their [`openzeppelin-contracts`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts) repo.

> "Solidity adds public getters to public state variables. This is kind
>   of magical and dark, and could lead to mistakes.
>
> We should be more explicit on everything we do, to make the code
>   clearer and easier to review. So let's get rid of the automatic
>   getters making all the public state variables private."

Comment: I believe that this answer is incomplete, since one could easy argue (in response to this answer): "well, why didn't they use `internal` instead of `private` then? The answer to that one, I believe, is that they wanted to explicitly state that these variables should not be "messed with" (i.e., altered) by anyone who chooses to inherit the corresponding contract.

Comment: And BTW, this change in OZ code (starting from v2.0.0 if I remember correctly), has actually caused an issue with extending `Ownable` to `Claimable`. They have removed `Claimable` at that point, and since `owner` has become `private`, it could no longer be altered by anyone who wished to implement his/her own version of `Claimable`.

Comment: Yep, fair points. I've answered the question with the publicly available information, that being the initial comment on the issue from the OZ dev. Without asking them directly - and perhaps someone close to the project can chime in and confirm either way - any further reasoning would be conjecture. What you're saying makes complete sense though :-)

Comment: @goodvibration Does it mean that public variables can potentially undergo security issues especially if someone choses to inherit the contract ? I don't get it, do a contract B that inherits from the contract A have the possibility to alter data of contract A and in particular its public variables ?

Comment: @KevinWad: Yes, for both `public` and `internal` variables of the parent contract. I wouldn't call it a security issue though. It's not like you can deploy `B` and then change variables of some other instance of `A`. You can only change your own variables (i.e., when you implement your `B` contract, you can change the variables declare at the `A` level, but those variables will be part of your `B` contract, not any other `B` contract out there).

Comment: Ok thank you very much. I am currently in the process of deploying a smart contract that wil be open source. I see you are very active on Stackoverflow. Before releasing I would like someone like you to review my code to see if there is something I did not see. If you agree send me an email or a phone number so that we can discuss it. Best regards

Comment: Ok check your email in the coming 1 to 3 weeks. Best regards